# Postfix wildcard, virtual_alias, and recipient_delimiter forwarding glitch

Tags: postfix, virtualhost, alias, wildcard

Using Postfix with an MySQL backend, have a group of aliases set up, including domain aliases.  Using '.' as recipient_delimiter, and have propagate_unmatched_extensions = canonical, virtual, alias.  Here's where it gets weird.  If I send tagged traffic to the alias user.tag2@example.net, I would expect postfix to forward it to user.tag2@machine.example.com, but instead the wildcard grabs it and pushes it's tag onto the stack (which it should if that were the case).

Remove tag2 from the message to 'user', and it forwards to 'user' properly.  Send wildcard traffic, and it forwards that with the tag pushed on the stack as expected.  It's as if the delimiter short-circuts the alias table scan and it drops straight into the wildcard search.  I've been digging through the canonical docs, forums, etc. and this one's is a little obscure a use-case, so if someone can point me in the right direction to fix this, that would be awesome!  I'm guessing there's a RE somewhere that's broken (not one of mine, all my junk is in milters and SQL), but finding it is like a needle in haystack...

=====UPDATE=====

Answered below, thanks folks!
=====END UPDATE=====

Historical Orig. Post:

I've distilled a test-case as follows:

domain alias table:
example.net -> machine.example.net

alias table:

@machine.example.net  ->  foo.tag1@machine.example.net

user@machine.example.net -> user@machine.example.com

Some SQL relating to aliases...

alias_catchall_maps.cf:

query = SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and alias.address = CONCAT('@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'

alias_mailbox_maps.cf:

query = SELECT maildir FROM mailbox,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and mailbox.username = CONCAT('%u', '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND mailbox.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'

alias_domain_maps.cf:

query = SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and alias.address = CONCAT('%u', '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'

alias_maps.cf:

query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='%s' AND active = '1'

Comment: You know how you can add `-v` in master.cf (to the smtpd and proxymap services, afair) to increase logging verbosity? That should clarify the order of lookups tried, and give examples of the resulting strings from those sql queries (I am looking for log entries like `dict_proxy_lookup: ..` and `input attribute value`).

Comment: @anx Great one, thank you! That was super helpful! After the first cycle of lookups/milters/smptd restrictions etc. and receiving the message, it iterates through proxymap and smtpd again and I see it is throwing the email address as the key into dict_proxy_lookup, with flags=lock|fold|fix, nothing gives a result until it gets to the catchall_maps.cf (the wildcard SQL query).  I'm wondering if dict_proxy_lookup even peels off the recipient delimiter **at all** in the case of alias maps, so now I'm off to look at the source and find out;  Back in a few...

Comment: ARGH! postfix[version]\src\virtural.c:
CASE FOLDING
All delivery decisions are made using the full recipient address, folded to lower case. 
TABLE SEARCH ORDER
Normally, a lookup table is specified as a text file that serves as input to the postmap command. The result, an indexed file in dbm/db format, is used for fast searching by the mail system. The search order is as follows. The search stops upon the first successful lookup.  When the recipient has an optional address extension the
user+extension@domain.tld address is looked up first. With <v2.1, the addr extension is always ignored.

Comment: Virtual aliasing is recursive, and case sensitive (its only folded for lookups that cannot deal with uppercase), so as long as the order of your lookups is correct (more specific results first), neither should be a problem.

Comment: Now my task is to write some query magick to selectively cut (more likely rank the wildcard results lower) when the recipient delimiter is present in the query string in an attempt to make this work 'smarter'..., again, @anx, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I think the default lookup order is what you want - least to most specific, are you sure you are not explicitly swapping it through the order of your tables like `virtual_alias_maps = type:less/specific, type:more/specific, ..`

Comment: Oh, this is also helpful, as it means I don't have to write a complicated stored iterative query.  Order should be most specific to least: Leave the first query as-is, a second similar query that regex's any recipient delimiter (if present) from the user search key.  That way, an alias can specify a delimiter, or the alias can just be for a username and propagate the recipient delimiter to it's destination as expected, finally the wildcard will catch the stragglers that match nothing.  Once I've thoroughly tested all this stuff, I'll edit OP with the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:  Added test code, hopefully the regex escapes survive translation, YMMV...**

THANK YOU @ANX for the advice to enable verbose logging on smtpd and proxymap, then looking for dict_proxy_lookup and input_attribute_value in the logs for hints to where postfix was going off in the weeds.  Test traffic revealed that it was in fact falling through to the last alias query (wildcard search) because it was passing the entire username, including the recipient delimiter, into the query.  So I got to looking at the source code.  Sure enough, in virtual.c, paraphrased here:
*CASE FOLDING All delivery decisions are made using the full recipient address, folded to lower case. TABLE SEARCH ORDER Normally, a lookup table is specified as a text file that serves as input to the postmap command. The result, an indexed file in dbm/db format, is used for fast searching by the mail system. The search order is as follows. The search stops upon the first successful lookup. When the recipient has an optional address extension the user+extension@domain.tld address is looked up first. With <v2.1, the addr extension is always ignored.*  I've been a long-time postfix user, and using virtual through the SQL proxy interface is a new experience for me, thus used to having delimiters stripped from the virtual hash tables and this was a surprise.  I understand why this was done (to give folks choice in rule creation).

TL;DR: Here is the issue in a nutshell: In smptd/virtual.c, all database queries are passed with the recipient delimiter in place. This leaves it up to the implementer to use it (or not) in their SQL query. Here is the 'fix': Add a special case query to the list of virtual alias maps, just before the wildcard query (mysql_virtual_alias_domain_nodelim_maps.c excerpt below) this one does a search with a regex cutting out the recipient delimiter from %u prior to the lookup, when all the prior lookups have failed, but before we fall back to the wildcard search:

main.cf:

virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf,

proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf,

proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_nodelim_maps.cf,  #<--new query

proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf

mysql_virtual_alias_domain_nodelim_maps.cf:  (I use '.' as a delimiter, YMMV)

query = SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d' and alias.address = CONCAT(REGEXP_REPLACE('%u', '\..*', ''), '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active='1'

It works great, and now one can set up a special alias for bar.foo tagged traffic, AND it will propagate the inbound tag at output at the end of the tag list if the alias has it's own tag which is really really cool!

BTW, I built a test case of the query set in python until satisfied it behaved similar to postfix.  Then started to futz with the regex until satisfied it solved the issue. After resolving the escaping differences between postfix and python, tried the new query out on a non-production postfix instance, and it behaves as intended.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

# dbhost, dbname, dbuser, dbpass with your parameters
dbhost = ''
dbname = ''
dbuser = ''
dbpass = ''

# Our setup predates DMARC, doing some pretty specialized work with
# address tagging, in particular tying a domain component to the To:
# address as a sub-tag for certain destinations.  This was particularly
# useful in wildcard email hoppers before SPF/DMARC became useful.

# RECIPIENT DELIMITER (. = gmail style)
rd = '.'
# DOMAIN DELIMITER (-)
dd = '-'
# EXAMPLE:
# myemailaddr.tag-domainlock@mydomain.com
# where:  tag = folder, or folder.folder, etc.
#         domianlock = site lock parameter

# parseTo(addr, tag_to_push, dom_to_push) 
# breaks an email To: field into constituent parts
# optionally pushes a recipient delimiter and domain
# tag onto the tag stack
def parseTo(to, tag='', dom=''):
    # To: input:
    #                [atag ]
    #         uname.tag-dom@domain
    #[    user             ]
    # uname.tag.tag-dom-dom@domain
    #[             full           ]
    # uname@domain
    #[   notags   ]
    rtv = {}
    to = to.lower()
    if '<' in to:
        to[to.find('<')+1:to.find('>')]
    rtv['user']   = to[:to.find('@')]
    rtv['uname']  = rtv['user']
    rtv['domain'] = to[to.find('@')+1:]
    rtv['atag']   = ''  # inbound tag
    rtv['tag']    = tag  # new tag for top of stack
    rtv['dom']    = dom  # new dom for top of stack
    if rd in rtv['user']:
        rtv['uname']  = rtv['user'][:rtv['user'].find(rd)]
        rtv['atag']  = rtv['user'][rtv['user'].find(rd)+1:]
        if rtv['tag'] != '':
            rtv['tag'] = rd + rtv['tag']
        if dd in rtv['atag']:
            rtv['tag'] = rtv['atag'][:rtv['atag'].find(dd)] + rtv['tag']
            if rtv['dom'] != '':
                rtv['dom'] = dd + rtv['dom']
            rtv['dom'] = rtv['atag'][rtv['atag'].find(dd)+1:] + rtv['dom']
        else:
            rtv['tag']  = rtv['atag'] + rtv['tag']
    rtv['full'] = rtv['uname']
    if rtv['tag'] != '':
        rtv['full'] += rd + rtv['tag']
    if rtv['dom'] != '':
        rtv['full'] += dd + rtv['dom']
    rtv['full'] += '@' + rtv['domain']
    rtv['notags'] = rtv['uname'] + '@' + rtv['domain']
    return rtv

# recurseUser(addr)
# try to match postfix address processing/order as close as possible...
# regex assumes recipient_delimiter = '.'
def recurseUser(addr):
    print("query alias: %s" % (addr))
    to = parseTo(addr)
    user = to['user']
    domain = to['domain']
    # postfix automatically runs the last case (@domain query) to all hashes as
    # well as the list provided to proxymap via the virtual directives in
    # main.cf by re-running the alias case.  Really, it likely will just iterate
    # over all of them but that is a waste given the structure of the virtual db.
    # Cases are run most specific to broadest (e.g. catch-all wildcards).
    # There is a rule specified *somewhere* that alias must contain all valid
    # destinations.  Postfixadmin enforces this for you.
    # try the alias table first with the full spec...
    q = ("SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address = %s AND active = 1 LIMIT 1")
    cursor.execute(q, (addr,))
    res = cursor.fetchone()
    if res is None:
        # next, check if there is a domain redirect to a specific subdomain alias entry.
        print("  ...not found, check alias domain: %s %s" % (domain, user))
        q = ("SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = %s and alias.address = CONCAT(%s, '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active=1")
        cursor.execute(q, (domain, user))
        res = cursor.fetchone()
        if res is None:
            # ***NEW*** strip any recipient delimiter and try the previous search again
            # this allows the creation of r_d specific aliases, or the use of r_d's with
            # wildcards in the domain cathall maps.  Aliases can also add their own tags,
            # which will be pushed to the top of stack by postix as a matter of course
            print("    ...not found, remove tags (if any) and check again: %s %s" % (domain, to['notags']))
            q = ("SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = %s and alias.address = CONCAT(REGEXP_REPLACE(%s, '\\\\..*', ''), '@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active=1")
            cursor.execute(q, (domain, user))
            res = cursor.fetchone()
            if res is None:
                # check for a wildcard query from domain catchall maps (for the cases of wc@bar.com -> wc@machine.bar.com)
                print("      ...not found, check wc in alias domain: %s" % (domain))
                q = ("SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = %s and alias.address = CONCAT('@', alias_domain.target_domain) AND alias.active = 1 AND alias_domain.active=1")
                cursor.execute(q, (domain,))
                res = cursor.fetchone()
                if res is None:
                    # lastly run the wildcard query for the target wildcard alias (for the cases of wc@machine.bar.com)
                    print("        ... not found, check wc in alias as: @%s" % (domain))
                    q = ("SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address = %s AND active = 1 LIMIT 1")
                    cursor.execute(q, ('@'+domain,))
                    res = cursor.fetchone()
                    if res is None:
                        print("          Not found, gave up!")
                        return addr
    # found a result, so push any new tags on the stack and recurse until the results are unchanged
    newto = parseTo(res['goto'], to['tag'], to['dom'])
    print("             got: %s" % (res))
    # compare sans tags, we're interested in the actual destination, and the tag stack may change
    # along the way
    if to['notags'] == newto['notags']:
        print("             done!")
        return addr
    print("             recurse...")
    return recurseUser(newto['full']) # otherwise, recurse...


if True:
    db = mysql.connector.connect(database=dbname, host=dbhost, user=dbuser, password=dbpass)
    cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    while True:
       test = input("Address to try ('q' to end): ")
       if test.lower() == 'q':
          cursor.close()
          db.close()
          quit()
       print("Result:", recurseUser(test))
       print("")
```